# Three questions regarding list and function operations in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I just had a few questions on list and function operations.

1) If I have a function `f[]` and a list `list`, I want to apply `f[]` sequentially to every element of the list, much like `Scan` does, but rather than `Map`, `Apply`, or even `Nest` does. How to do this?

2) If I have a list `list` and an index list `ind`, how can I assign values to the corresponding elements given another list of values? `Map[list[[#]] &, ind] = value_list` will give `Set::write: Tag Map in ... is Protected` error.

3) How to apply a function `f[]` `n` times and form a result list, instead of composing the function `n` times as the function `Nest` does? Is it `Map[f[],Range[n]]`?

**EDIT**

In response to the comment, here are a few simple examples all involving how to set elements with specified indices to zero in a list. There examples are supposed for illustrating purposes. Of course, there must be better options to do these tasks. I just tired these out before coming to the working one like `setZeroWithIndex[list_, ind_] := Module[{}, list[[ind]] = ConstantArray[0, Length[ind]]; 
Return[list]];`

1) `setZeroWithIndex[list_, ind_] := Scan[ReplacePart[list, # -> 0] &, ind];`. This does not work. Replacing `Scan` with `Map`, `Apply` etc. does not work either.

2）`setZeroWithIndex[list_, ind_] := Map[list[[#]] &, ind] = ConstantArray[0, Length[ind]];
mylist = Range[20]; setZeroWithIndex[mylist, {2, 4, 6}]`. Got the error I posted.

3) `setZeroWithRandomIndex[list_] := ReplacePart[list, RandomInteger[{1,Length[list]}] -> 0]`. Now I just want to apply `setZeroWithRandomIndex` `n` times instead of functionally composing it many times. `NestList` does not seem to work here.

Comment: I think an example of each case may be useful, at least for those like me whose English communication skills are nil.

Comment: I think you are tying to assign values to values, instead of symbols

Answer (score 4):

`Scan`, or `Do` will do exactly that. Try `Scan[f, list]` or `Do[f@el, {el, list}]`.

Regarding 2), you should use `Part`. For instance `list[[{ind}]] = a` will change elements as needed. If `a` is a vector of the same length as `ind`, then appropriate threading will occur.

3) You should look at `NestList`.